# Sum of powered numbers

Tags: summation

Here is what I have achieved so far:

> $S(n,p)= 1^p+2^p...+n^p$

By arranging it this way:

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1^{p-1}$

$\ \ \ \ 2^{p-1} 2^{p-1}$

$3^{p-1} 3^{p-1} 3^{p-1}$

$..............$

I found that:

> $S(n,p) = (n+1)S(n,p-1) - Sum(k=1 to n)S(k,p-1)$

So if I have the formula like $S(n,2)= 1^2...+n^2$, I can easily find the formula for the next $S(n,3)$ as any other $S(n,p)$ formula.

What I try to achieve is if I have $S(n,p)$ I want to be able to find $S(n,p-1)$. By able I mean I need to have $S(n,p)$ as the open (with sum) and $S(n,p-1)$ as a closed form(no sum) in the seeked formula.Or both closed form(no sums at all in the final formula).

What I have tried is to express the sum: $A = \sum_{k=1}^{n}S(k,p-1)$  to something else, however I found that $A= (n+1)S(n,p-1) - S(n,p)$ so in the end I got that $0=0$, dead end.

Comment: What is your question??? In any event, $s(n,p) = \frac{B_{p+1}(n+1)-B_{p+1}(0)}{p+1}$ where $B_p(x)$ is the [Bernoulli polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials) of degree $p$. See [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) for more details about the sum of powers.

Comment: Hint: If $p$ is a positive integer, then $(k+1)^{p+1}-k^{p+1}$ can be expressed (using the binomial theorem) as $(p+1)k^p$ plus a linear combination of lower powers of $k$. Add up $k=1$ to $n$.

Comment: I want to express formula like S(n,p) = (n+1)S(n,p-1) - Sum(k=1 to n)S(k,p-1) but inversed. By inversed I mean I want to get something like that: S(n,p-1) = (n+1)S(n,p) - Sum(k=1 to n)S(k,p) in other words: if you have S(n,100) i want to be able to find S(n,99).